# StackOverflowError during reduce of Flux

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have a problem, that reducing 3000 integers from Flux throws StackOverflowError

```
final var list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i < 3000; i++) {
    list.add(i);
}
final Tuple2<Integer, List<Integer>> block = Flux.fromIterable(list)
    .reduce(
        Mono.just(Tuple.of((Integer) null, List.<Integer>empty())),
        (initial, next) -> initial.map(
            init -> Tuple.of(next, init._2().append(next))
        )
    )
    .flatMap(Function.identity())
    .block();

System.out.println(block);
```

I don't understand where is a problem here, as I don't think that processing 3000 Integers should fill stack

The problem I think is connected with Mono inside of reduce because this is working properly:

```
final Tuple2<Integer, List<Integer>> block = Flux.fromIterable(list)
    .reduce(
        Tuple.of((Integer) null, List.<Integer>empty()),
        (initial, next) -> Tuple.of(next, initial._2().append(next))
    )
    .block();
```

Comment: Can you explain what you want to achieve? Your logic is a bit complex its hard to read that code.

Comment: The problem is that my init MUST BE Mono<T>
because my T has a method that returns Mono<T>. I want to apply reduce with flatMapping multiple times. Locally where I use flatMap in reduce for ~600 time it throws stackOverflow

Comment: This is a known, won't-fix issue in reactor: https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/issues/1441 You can't safely chain operators that way. Depending on your use case, there might be a workaround but it's not clear what the exact goal is from the code sample.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand your problem. I would use zip for that

```
var res = Mono.zip(Mono.just(new ArrayList<Integer>()), Flux.fromIterable(list)
        .collectList())
        .flatMap(c -> {
            c.getT1().addAll(c.getT2());
            return Mono.just(c.getT1());
        })
```

Where `Mono.just(new ArrayList<Integer>())` - is your Mono
Then in flat map you will get your list and your mono, you can do what ever you want

Comment: I reproduced an issue with simpler code I have in my production code which I cannot paste here.